# Dynamics CRM 2016, custom datetime incorrect when created by plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

We have Dynamics crm 2016 version 8.1.0.

A post  create plugin creates a task and enters a Date into a custom Date field on the task.
there is a log which writes the value of the date field to a log entity before creation, and the value there is correct.

The task is created with the date field and **the value is 3 hours later**.

The CRM is in local zone UTC+2, if the time was 2/3 hours earlier , I would assume the UTC date is entered.

What can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin ran in user context of System, changing it to a user with system administrator privilege, bypassed the problem.